# How can I compare the columns of 2 tables from 2 different datatables?

Tags: sql

I need to compare the columns of two different tables from two different databases. Is there a way I can do this? I basically need to check if the columns within these two tables are the same or where they are different. I would like to list out the columns of these two tables side by side.

- Table 1: abc.table1
- Table 2: xyz.table2

Comment: What is your RDBMS, please? (Oracle, MS Sql, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that simply by using 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS' for SQL Server.
**TO FIND SAME Columns IN (SQL SERVER)**

```
SELECT T1.* FROM 
(SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM [DatabaseName1].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table1'
) T1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM [DatabaseName2].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table2'
) T2 ON T1.COLUMN_NAME=T2.COLUMN_NAME
```

**To Find Uncommon Column**

```
SELECT T1.* FROM 
(SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM [DatabaseName1].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table1'
) T1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM [DatabaseName1].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table2'
) T2 ON T1.COLUMN_NAME=T2.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE T2.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL
```

**Note:** This will work for SQL Server only.

Comment: Hi There! Do you think there is a way to list out all the columns from Table 1: abc.table1 that are not found in Table 2: xyz.table2?

Comment: @Charlie I did't understand what you actually asked for. can you explain little more?

Comment: Well originally I wanted to verify all the columns in one table vs the other table. Now, I was a list of columns that are in Table1 that do not belong in Table2.

Comment: How can I check which columns found in table 1 are not in table 2?

Comment: TABLE 1 COLUMNS -> ID, NAME, PHONE_NUMBER////////
TABLE 2 COLUMNS --> ID, DATE, PHONE_NUMBER//////
RESULT: NAME///////
(Since the column name is in Table 1 but not found in Table 2)

Comment: @Charlie Sorry, firstly I have misunderstood what you actually wanted. But now I think I have understand it properly. I have updated my answer. Please check now. It should work in sql server.